# Ember.js add observer when content is completely loaded

Tags: ember.js

Having issues getting my observer setup correctly.  The following code works fine in the sense that it seems to observe the length property correctly.  However, it fires repeatedly while the page is loading up, which isn't what I'd expect/want.  Is there a way to add this observer on complete load?

```
App.PlaylistController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  songsChanged: function() {
   // some behaviour
  }.observes('content.songs.length'),
});
```

For what it's worth, this.get('content.isLoaded'); returns true when loading the page

```
App.PlaylistController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  songsChanged: function() {
   this.get('content.isLoaded');
  }.observes('content.songs.length'),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically add and remove observers in ember using [Ember.Observable.addObserver](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Observable.html#method_removeObserver) and [Ember.Observable.removeObserver](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Observable.html#method_removeObserver) respectively.

In your case you probably want to observe 'content.isLoaded' property and in the observer dynamically add the 'content.songs.length' observer afterwards using the mentioned addObserver function.